# How to write JSONP Ajax request on pure js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

```
$.ajax( { url : '', data: {}, dataType:'jsonp',  jsonpCallback: 'callbackName', type: 'post'
        ,success:function (data) {
        console.log('ok');
        },
        error:function () {
        console.log('error');
        }
        });
```

How do I write the same functionality in pure JS?

Comment: You use XMLHttpRequest. Lots of examples on how to do this out there. Here's one: http://codeislife.org/javascript/pure-javascript-ajax-190 Just search the google for "pure javascript ajax"

Comment: Why is Ajax superior or so much more common?

Comment: I tried this code. 
But it throws an error, as well as all 'Error in request'

Comment: JSONP and `POST` - am I missing something? JSONP is actually a way to (cross site) request data by a `script` tag that's injected to the page DOM (naturally leading to a `GET` request), executing the function call defined in the Javascript response to handle the data. From this point @Kevin B's answer is perfectly correct. Your API looks strange.

Comment: @joelmdev ironically, this question pops at the top of the results for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, you aren't making an ajax call at all, instead you're making a JSONP request. Luckily, these are incredibly easy to replicate and work in all browsers.

```
var s = document.createElement("script"),
    callback = "jsonpCallback_" + new Date().getTime(),
    url = "http://forexplay.net/ajax/quotes.php?callback=" + callback;
window[callback] = function (data) {
    // it worked!
    console.log(data);
};
s.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Note, this performs a GET request, it isn't possible to perform a POST jsonp request.

Comment: but what if I need to run the code recursively?

Comment: .... really? put it in a function.

Comment: JSONP was intended to request data cross domain. The way Kevin shows is perfectly right. I would rather challenge why the TO is sending JSONP on `POST` where pure JSON would be ok OK.

Answer (score 8):

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", 'http://forexplay.net/ajax/quotes.php');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            console.log('Response: ' + xmlhttp.responseText );
        }else{
            console.log('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText )
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

I'm always forgetting about capital and small letters in XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I tried this code. 
But it throws an error, as well as all 'Error in request'

Comment: I finaly understood what did you mean. Look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/3641231)

Comment: xmlhttp.status == 2 xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: This is not JSONP...